# Bitvise : the ssh session has terminated with error. reason flowsocketreader: Error receiving bytes. Windows error 10054

Tags: linux, ssh, connection, debian

I'm using Debian and connecting it to Bit vise SSH server, I configured everything is /etc/ssh/sshd_config but when I try to connect using root and its password I get this Error:

> **The SSH session has terminated with error. Reason: FlowSocketReader: Error receiving bytes. Windows error 10054: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.**

Is there anyway to fix this? I've been searching all night please help

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not questions about using or setting up Linux. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: wrong area of asking help, this is for coding only

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

1. Make sure the bitvise version is above v7.42
2. choose Elevation: Yes, in the Authentication-section of the Login-tab dropdown.
   Ref: https://vvcares.com/blog/bitvise-connecting-error-localsshdisconn/